# Physic-based fur/hair on an already animated model from an external software (Source Filmmaker)?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, hair

So, I was looking up tutorials on physic-based hair or fur in Blender. However, while I found a ton of different tutorials on the subject, I couldn't find one where you could just overlay the fur or hair onto an already animated model. I'm already relatively familiar with animating in another software known as Source Filmmaker (SFM), and I find it far easier to use than Blender. However, it is also severely outdated, so it would simply crash if I were to use a high-poly model. I was thinking I could take the animation I made in SFM and apply it to a high-poly model in Blender, and then add the fur/hair to it. But I really want the hair or fur to be physics-based, not static. Is there any way to do this? Or would it just be easier to learn animation in Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how I can help except point you to a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxbW5mCdHLg
Animation import as fbx will work.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it :)